# Make static libtool library with no source files

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, autotools, libtool

Using autotools and libtool, I need to merge several libraries in subdirectories into a bigger static library in toplevel directory. Here is schema:

```
# src/Makefile.am

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS} -I m4                                                                                                                               
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects                                                                                                                                      

SUBDIRS = foo bar .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libbig.la                                                                                                                     

libbig_la_LIBADD = \                                                                                                                               
    foo/libfoo.la \
    foo/libbar.la
```

In sub-directories:

```
# src/foo/Makefile.am

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS} -I m4                                                                                                                               

noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la                                                                                                                     

libbig_la_SOURCES = \                                                                                                                               
    foo.cpp \
    foo_ji.cpp
```

It says no rule to make target `libbig.la`. Is it possible to make a library (static or shared) using no source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to read `libfoo_la_SOURCES` and `libbig_la_SOURCES` and `libbig_la_LIBADD`

Comment: But... I don't have any sources, just two static libraries

Comment: Add the moment you don't have any rule to add anything to libbig.la because you missed the _la_ everywhere